# JQuery UI Sortable - How to sort two types of items in one container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to sort two types of items (different class name) in same container.
Each type of items should be sorted between itself without interfere the other items type.

I try this code: but it didn't work:

```
$('#myItemsContainer').sortable({
    items: '.sortType1',
    start: function(event, ui) {
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
    }
});

$('#myItemsContainer').sortable({
    items: '.sortType2',
    start: function(event, ui) {
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myItemsContainer">

<div class="sortType1">Item Type 1</div>
<div class="sortType1">Item Type 1</div>
<div class="sortType1">Item Type 1</div>

<div class="sortType2">Item Type 2</div>
<div class="sortType2">Item Type 2</div>
<div class="sortType2">Item Type 2</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This does not make sense. Since all the items are in the same container, they are essentially listed together. If you do not want them sorted together, you should consider moving them to their own containers.

Comment: @Twisty Thank you for you reply. For now, I try a work around using mouseOver event one item type. So if the element is of item type 1, I call the sortable function for items type 1 and destroy the sortable of the items type 2 (and vice versa). This way the container is still the same and I can use multiple types not just 2 types. But I was hoping there's another official way.

Comment: You are essentially re-initializing Sortable with a new set of options, so there is no way to do it on the same container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you must contain them in their own container. Here is an example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myItemsContainer .list:eq(0)").sortable({
    items: "> .sortType1"
  });
  $("#myItemsContainer .list:eq(1)").sortable({
    items: "> .sortType2"
  });
});
```

```css
#myItemsContainer {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#myItemsContainer div[class^='sortType'] {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="myItemsContainer">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="sortType1">Item Type 1</div>
    <div class="sortType1">Item Type 1</div>
    <div class="sortType1">Item Type 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="sortType2">Item Type 2</div>
    <div class="sortType2">Item Type 2</div>
    <div class="sortType2">Item Type 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve such behavior by updating `items` option of `sortable` widget. And, you can update it on mouseover on the items:

```html
<div id="myItemsContainer">

    <div class="sortType1">Item Type 1</div>
    <div class="sortType1">Item Type 1</div>
    <div class="sortType1">Item Type 1</div>

    <div class="sortType2">Item Type 2</div>
    <div class="sortType2">Item Type 2</div>
    <div class="sortType2">Item Type 2</div>

</div>
```

```js
$(function() {

    var elm = $('#myItemsContainer'); // cache for performance

    elm.sortable({
        items: '> .sortType1' // start with default selector
    }).on('mouseover', 'div', function(e) {

        if ($(e.currentTarget).hasClass('sortType1')) {
            // limit items to sortType1
            elm.sortable('option', 'items', '> .sortType1');
        } else {
            // limit items to sortType2
            elm.sortable('option', 'items', '> .sortType2');
        }
    });
});
```